# agregar una nueva propiedad a un objeto JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Hola estoy tratando de agregarle una nueva propiedad a cada uno de los objetos del array productos,  esta propiedad se llama precio y debe venir del array precios.

hice dos for anidados pero todos los objetos del array productos tiene solo un valor 2500

Como puedo asignar los valores correctamente

Gracias por la ayuda

```js
const productos = [
  {
    id: 1,
    nombre: "producto 1",
    descripcion: "lorem ipsum 1"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    nombre: "producto 2",
    descripcion: "lorem ipsum 2"
  }
]

const precios = [
  {
    precio: 1200
  },
  {
    precio: 2500
  }
]

for(let i=0; i<productos.length; i++){
  for(let j=0; j<precios.length; j++){
    productos[i].precios = precios[j].precio
  }
}

console.log(productos);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solo necesitas un `for`.

```js
const productos = [
  {
    id: 1,
    nombre: "producto 1",
    descripcion: "lorem ipsum 1"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    nombre: "producto 2",
    descripcion: "lorem ipsum 2"
  }
]

const precios = [
  {
    precio: 1200
  },
  {
    precio: 2500
  }
]

for(let i=0; i<productos.length; i++){
   productos[i].precios = precios[i].precio
}

console.log(productos);
```